# Changing product status with Magento (1.9) script not visible in Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-images, status

I'm trying to get all product without image to desactivate them.
I started from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565377/how-can-i-find-all-products-without-images-in-magento

At first, it was just to extract products without images, and it was working fine, but now I need to disable them and it's half working.

The problem is, when the code return that the status has changed, when I go back in Magento Admin, the product is still enable. (cache and indexes refreshed)

But when I run again the code, the status has changed and I can't see the product on the site.

So the code is working BUT I don't know why the admin product manager can't see that change.

I didn't find threads where I can get a glimpse of a solution. 
Maybe I'm just doing all wrong and I can't PROPERLY change the status from a collection.

Here my php file (mymagento/var/import/dev/test.php) :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once('../../../app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$storeId = 1; //check in magento admin
echo "Store ID : ".$storeId."\n<br />\n";
//this builds a collection that's analagous to 
//select * from products where image = 'no_selection'
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array (
            'attribute' => 'image',
            'like' => 'no_selection'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'image',
                'null' => '1'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'small_image',
                'null' => '1'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'thumbnail',
                'null' => '1'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'image',
                'nlike' => '%/%/%'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'small_image',
                'nlike' => '%/%/%'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'thumbnail',
                'nlike' => '%/%/%'
            )
        ),
        null,
        'left'
    );
echo  "SKU;NAME;VISIBLE;STATUS\n<br />\n";
foreach($products as $product)
{   
    $product->load();

    if($product->getVisibility() == 4 && $product->getStatus() == 1) {
        echo  $product->getSku() . ";".$product->getName().";".$product->getVisibility().";".$product->getStatus()."\n<br />\n";
        try {
            Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product->getId(), $storeId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
            echo "Product #".$product->getSku()." : Status changed to ".$product->getStatus().". \n<br />\n";
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "Product #".$product->getSku()." Status could not be changed: ".$e->getMessage()."\n<br />\n";
        }
    }
    try {
        $product->save();
        echo "Product #".$product->getSku()." : saved\n<br />\n";
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        echo "Product #".$product->getSku()." could not be saved: ".$e->getMessage();
    }                        
}
```

It's just a script to run 1 time to get rid of products without images to start on good bases for the next update.

Thank you for your time !

Comment: it might help you :- http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42014/hide-products-without-images-ce-1-9

Comment: are you running the script with caching enabled or disabled in Magento?

Comment: @Arunendra Thank you but it seems it's not the same problem.

Comment: @paj : I'm caching enabled product without images to disable them.

Comment: I mean if you disable the system cache, then run your script do you see the correct results in the backend.

Comment: I've no cache system activated on my dev. env., I updated my question trying to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came with a solution.

My problem was not fully related to my code.
When in admin product panel, I was looking at the default view of my product who was enable when the scope of my code was only for the EN store (which was disable when I switched the view).

I was not looking the product from the good store...

Anyway, I had to disable the product on both default and EN store.

Moreover, I find that some of my product did not have image selected **BUT** had images in the media gallery.

So, I add a condition when the script find no image selected, it has to look the media gallery to see if images are in it. If there are, I took the first image and add it to.

The only problem is that it **ADD** the image to the gallery media. That's mean I've got the images in it, **twice**, because I couldn't find a way to just add the image in the gallery to the images/thumbnail/small_image attributes. but it's another problem.

For instance, here my nearly final code :

```
<?
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once('../../../app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

// Variable init
global $defautStoreId;
global $frStoreId; 
global $statusChangedCount;
global $imagesUpdatedCount;
$relativePath = "../../../media/catalog/product/"; // path for the images
$defautStoreId = 0;
$frStoreId = 1; //check in magento admin
$statusChangedCount = 0;
$imagesUpdatedCount = 0;
$start = time();
echo "Store ID : ".$frStoreId."\n<br />\n";

//this builds a collection that's analagous to 
//select * from products where image = 'no_selection'
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->setStoreId($frStoreId)
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array("nlike" => "configurable")) // filter out configurable product
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array("eq" => 1)) // filter out configurable product
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array("eq" => 4)) // filter in visible product
    // ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array("eq" => 32501634)) //ID product for debug
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array (
            'attribute' => 'image',
            'like' => 'no_selection'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'image',
                'null' => '1'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'small_image',
                'null' => '1'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'thumbnail',
                'null' => '1'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'image',
                'nlike' => '%/%/%'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'small_image',
                'nlike' => '%/%/%'
            ),
            array(
                'attribute' => 'thumbnail',
                'nlike' => '%/%/%'
            )
        ),
        null,
        'left'
    );
echo "Total products : ".count($products)."\n<br />\n";
echo  "SKU;NOM;VISIBILITE;STATUS\n<br />\n";
foreach($products as $product)
{   
    //Loading product and gallery
    $product->load($product->getId());
    $mediaGallery = $product->getMediaGallery();
    //echo "<pre><xmp>".print_r($product->getData(), true)."</xmp></pre>\n<br />\n"; //uncomment to see all product attributes
    echo  $product->getSku() . ";".$product->getName().";".$product->getVisibility().";".$product->getStatus()."\n<br />\n";
    // echo  $product->getImage() . ";<pre><xmp>".print_r($mediaGallery, true)."</xmp></pre>\n<br />\n";
    if ($mediaGallery["images"] == NULL) {
        disableProduct($product->getId(), $product->getSku());
    } else {
        $mediaAttribute = array (
            'image',
            'thumbnail',
            'small_image'                  
        );
        // getting the path of the first image
        $filepath_to_image = $relativePath.$mediaGallery["images"][0]["file"];
        // add image to gallery and 
        try {
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filepath_to_image, $mediaAttribute, true, false);
            echo "Product #".$product->getSku()." image added to gallery.\n<br />\n";
            $imagesUpdatedCount++;
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            //If exception caught, disable product
            echo "Product #".$product->getSku()." Error while adding image :".$e->getMessage()."\n<br />\n";
            disableProduct($product->getId(), $product->getSku());
        }
    }
    // save the product
    try {
        $product->save();
        echo "Product #".$product->getSku()." : saved\n<br />\n";
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        echo "Product #".$product->getSku()." could not be saved: ".$e->getMessage();
    }                    
} 
echo "Total status changed : ".$statusChangedCount."\n<br />\n";
echo "Total images updated : ".$imagesUpdatedCount."\n<br />\n";
$end = time();  
echo "Elapsed time : ".($end-$start)." seconds";
// Disable function
function disableProduct($productId, $productSku) {
    global $defautStoreId;
    global $frStoreId; 
    global $statusChangedCount;
    try {
            Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($productId, $frStoreId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
            Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($productId, $defautStoreId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
            echo "Product #".$productSku." Status changed.\n<br />\n";
            $statusChangedCount++;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "Product #".$productSku." Status could not be changed: ".$e->getMessage()."\n<br />\n";
    }
}
?>
```

I think I can improve it especially for the disable part function and the addImageToMedia part. But no time for this anymore.

Another precision, when I tested this on 1200 product, I got an 500 internal server error. Only 30 products has not been processed. You may want add a limitation to 1000 products to run it correctly.